# Pytest not collecting tests in dependency order

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using `pytest` to test my package and I'm facing problems with dependency of tests, cause `pytest` is collecting (and testing) the sequence in alphabetical order, while it should be in dependency order. How can I change it?

**More details:**

The sequence of test it should runis:

1. `materials`: Needs nothing
2. `onerodtraction`, `onerodtorsion`, `onerodbending`: Needs (1)
3. `onerodallcharges`: Needs the three above (2)
4. `examples`: Needs the (3)

When I run I receive:

```
tests\test_examples.py ssssssssssss                                                         [ 22%]
tests\test_material.py ...                                                                  [ 27%]
tests\test_onerodallcharges.py sss                                                          [ 33%]
tests\test_onerodbending.py ..................                                              [ 66%]
tests\test_onerodtorsion.py .........                                                       [ 83%]
tests\test_onerodtraction.py .........                                                      [100%]
```

As we see, every test in the third file is skipped, and then the same happens for the first file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can try this `pytest_order`

```
pip install pytest-order
```

After installing you can mark on your classes.

https://pytest-dev.github.io/pytest-order/stable/usage.html#markers-on-class-level

In the each python file on each class specify the order as said

```
@pytest.mark.order(1)
class test_onerodtraction:

@pytest.mark.order(1)
class test_onerodtorsion:

@pytest.mark.order(1)
class test_onerodbending:
```

and now

```
@pytest.mark.order(2)
class test_onerodallcharges:
```

and then

```
@pytest.mark.order(3)
class test_examples.py:
```

Comment: You could also use [before and after markers](https://pytest-dev.github.io/pytest-order/stable/usage.html#order-relative-to-other-tests) in `pytest-order`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen yes. That is a good thing too.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `pytest-dependency`

- With order if you want to add a test case in middle, reordering will be required.
- parallel execution wont be effective.

https://pytest-dependency.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html

Comment: `pytest-dependency` doesn't order the tests by itself - you can use it together with `pytest-order` with the [--sort-dependencies](https://pytest-dev.github.io/pytest-order/stable/configuration.html#order-dependencies) option to achieve this.